# Putting a python path on a windows machine

Tags: python, windows

I am a mac user and have never really used a pc from the command line.

How would I add `django-admin.py` to my path, so I can type in

`> django-admin.py startproject newproject`.

I suppoed I'd need to do the following:

```
1 - Find the python executable `django-admin.py`
2 - Add it to my system path
3 - > ln -s PATH/TO/django-admin.py <my system path>
```

I know this is a very newbie question, but I'm having trouble 'getting started' on a new windows system to create a new django project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow this tutorial. You need to add its full path to 'path' variable.

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Thanks, and where would the executable `django-admin.py` normally be stored on a pc?

Comment: I am not really python guy, so not sure of python conventions.Like For example ruby 1.8.7 is installed in c:\ruby187.  It looks like by default the django goes into C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django

Comment: Its in `C:\Python27\Scripts` if you are using Python 2.7 - replace the path to wherever Python is installed.